# How to add the value from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition

I am extracting from the log file and print using the below code

```
for line in data:
    g = re.findall(r'([\d.]+).*?(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)', line)
    print (g)

[('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')]
[('2.2.2.2', 'GET')]
[('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')]
[('2.2.2.2', 'POST')]
```

How to add to the output

output

```
1.1.1.1: PUT = 2
2.2.2.2: GET = 1,POST=1
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by How to add to the output?

Comment: Are you trying to count for each address the number of occurrence of each requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to count:

```
# initialize the count dict
count_dict= dict()
for line in data:
    g = re.findall(r'([\d.]+).*?(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)', line)
    for tup in g:
        # get the counts for tuple tup if we don't have it yet
        # use 0 (second argument to .get)
        num= count_dict.get(tup, 0)
        # increase the count and write it back
        count_dict[tup]= num+1
# now iterate over the key (tuple) - value (counts)-pairs
# and print the result
for tup, count in count_dict.items():
    print(tup, count)
```

Ok, I have to admit this doesn't give the exact output, you want, but from this you can do in a similar manner:

```
out_dict= dict()
for (comma_string, request_type), count in count_dict.items():
    out_str= out_dict.get(comma_string, '')
    sep='' if out_str == '' else ', '
    out_str= f'{out_str}{sep}{request_type} = {count}'
    out_dict[comma_string]= out_str

for tup, out_str in out_dict.items():
    print(tup, out_str)
```

From your data that outputs:

```
1.1.1.1 PUT = 2
2.2.2.2 GET = 1, POST = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look towards Counter.

```
from collections import Counter
results = []
for line in data:
    g = re.findall(r'([\d.]+).*?(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)', line)
    results.append(g[0])
ip_list = set(result[0] for result in results)
for ip in ip_list:
    print(ip, Counter(result[1] for result in results if result[0] == ip ))
```

Comment: That's neat. I like it. Just changed the print-line (you were just missing the `if...`, so your solution printed the same (total) counts for each line, now it works. It should read `print(ip, Counter(result[1] for result in results if result[0] == ip ))`

Comment: Oh, just checked twice, you could even avoid the `ip_list` which would make it even shorter. You could just do `for ip, request_types in results:` and in the loop `print(ip, Counter(request_types)`.

Comment: Good catch with the if clause. 
I think `Counter(request_types)` would blow it up, as Counter consumes iterables and mappings -> Counter would output letter counts of `request_types`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collection.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for line in data:
    for ip, method in re.findall(r'([\d.]+).*?(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)', line):
        result[ip].append(method)

for k, v in result.items():
    temp = ""
    for i in set(v):
        temp += " {} = {}".format(i, v.count(i))
    print("{}{}".format(k, temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter  
x = [[('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')],[('2.2.2.2', 'GET')],[('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')],[('2.2.2.2', 'POST')]]
# step 1: convert x into a dict.
m = {}
for i in x:
    a, b = i[0]
    if a not in m.keys():
        m[a] = [b] 
    else: 
        x = m[a] 
        x.append(b)
        m[a] = x    
print('new dict is {}'.format(m))

# step 2 count frequency
m_values = list(m.values())
yy = []
for i in m_values:
    x = []
    k = list(Counter(i).keys())
    v = list(Counter(i).values())
    for i in range(len(k)):       
        x.append(k[i] + '=' + str(v[i]))
    yy.append(x)

# step 3, update the value of the dict
m_keys =  list(m.keys())
n = len(m_keys)
for i in range(n):
    m[m_keys[i]] = yy[i]

print("final dict is{}".format(m))
```

Output is

```
new dict is {'1.1.1.1': ['PUT', 'PUT'], '2.2.2.2': ['GET', 'POST']}
final dict is{'1.1.1.1': ['PUT=2'], '2.2.2.2': ['GET=1', 'POST=1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without dependencies and using a dict for counting, in a very basic way. Given the `data_set`:

```
data_set = [[('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')],
            [('2.2.2.2', 'GET')],
            [('2.2.2.2', 'POST')],
            [('1.1.1.1', 'PUT')]]
```

Initialize the variables (manually, just few verbs) then iterate over the data:

```
counter = {'PUT': 0, 'GET': 0, 'POST': 0, 'DELETE': 0}
res = {}

for data in data_set:
  ip, verb = data[0]
  if not ip in res:
    res[ip] = counter
  else:
    res[ip][verb] += 1

print(res)
#=> {'1.1.1.1': {'PUT': 1, 'GET': 0, 'POST': 1, 'DELETE': 0}, '2.2.2.2': {'PUT': 1, 'GET': 0, 'POST': 1, 'DELETE': 0}}
```

It's required to format the output to better fits your needs.